# When changing states in a finite state machine, how can I interrupt the current state's execution?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, state-machine

I'm running a finite state machine in Unity, but I feel like this is a pure C# problem anyways. The state machine has states that more or less have the following structure

```
public abstract class BaseState
{
   public StateMachine stateMachine;   

   public abstract void EnterState();
   
   public abstract void UpdateState();

   public abstract void ExitState();
}
```

For purposes of execution, the state machine will update the current state every frame, and depending on the state's logic, the state machine can be told to switch from the current state to another. The flow goes more or less as follows:

```
stateA.UpdateState()
-----
stateA.UpdateState()
-----
stateA.UpdateState <- in this frame, the state decides that the machine needs to switch over to stateB)
stateMachine.ChangeState(stateB)
stateA.ExitState()
stateB.EnterState()
-----
stateB.UpdateState()
-----
stateB.UpdateState()
```

The issue comes from the fact that the current state's UpdateState function doesn't just stop when it's state is exited from, so the execution order basically looks like

```
> Everything in stateA.UpdateState() leading up to the state change 
> Exit stateA
> Enter stateB
> Everything ELSE in stateB.UpdateState() after the state change
```

**Now, that last step is what I want to remove.** The simplest solution is to just `return` after the logic that changes the state. However, let's look at what my current situation looks like

```
   public void UpdateState(float deltaTime)
   {
      FunctionA(); // All of these can change to any other of the states
      FunctionB(); //    at any given point, if the conditions set within
      FunctionC(); //    are met, as well as change internal variables
      FunctionD(); //    of the state, which I'd like to prevent.
   }
```

I can't return twice from inside any of those functions, and setting something like an `enabled` flag in the state and adding `if (!enabled) return;` after *every function* sounds like a bad practice, and hard to keep track of, particularly if any of those functions have other functions they call that can change the state.

Speaking of terrible practices—and please put down your pitchforks—for my first attempt I went with an anti-pattern! I decided that, since I'm not using threading or async functions, the only non-flag way to stop the execution of what remained in the function was to exception my way out! I implemented a custom StateEndedException, and now the code in the state machine basically looks like this

```
public class StateMachine
{
   State currentState;

   void UpdateState()
   {
      try
      {
         currentState.UpdateState();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         if (e is not StateEndedException) throw e;
      }
   }

   void ChangeState(State newState)
   {
      currentState.ExitState();
      newState.EnterState();
      currentState = newState;
      throw new StateEndedException();
   }
}
```

Because the stack goes `stateMachine.Update > State.Update > stateMachine.ChangeState`, the exception arrives back at the UpdateState function, and it catches the exception with only a bit of complaining in the Unity console, interrupting everything in the previous state's Update function.

Now, this "works", but it's just *horrid*, this is nothing more than a fancy `goto`. Do you suggest any alternatives? Of course, if you tell me that just using an `enabled` flag is the most widely accepted way to go, I can respect that, I just wanted to check if I'm missing something obvious out there.

Comment: Pretty creative the use of exception, sounds pretty wrong, but its creative. I don't know if im totally following u, when you call a change state the Exit state should be responsable to properly close the state, and if this isn't inside a routine, it will change the state before the next frame start, which means that on the next state the Update of the new state should run, but the way that you said its like things will run some part of StateA and when exited it will finish with the rest of StateB, with does not make sense at all as you don't have a routine on update and ...

Comment: ... the update method would run by a whole before goes to the next script.

Comment: Ouh, wait, do you have multiple scripts depending on this MS and what you mean is that after you change state the remaining scripts will run the update from the new state?

Comment: How about instead of change the state on the exact moment that you call it, you delay it to the end of the frame? You can easily make this check on the monobehavior that is passing the sm state to unity message through LateUpdate